# Checkout from svn error

Tags: android, eclipse, svn

I'm trying to checkout this library project http://code.google.com/p/android-color-picker/source/checkout via eclipse with http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x installed.

site says: svn checkout http://android-color-picker.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ android-color-picker-read-only

when I try this I get the following error:

`Bad URL passed to RA layer`
`svn: URL 'http://android-color-picker.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/%20android-color-picker-read-only' non-existent in revision 2`

Can someone help?
Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is no such URL. I don't know where you got it from.

Go up one level. Enter http://android-color-picker.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ into a browser. You will see that it has only one subdirectory: "AmbilWarna".

Perhaps your source for this URL is out of date.

Comment: Thanks that's sorted it for me. The page at http://code.google.com/p/android-color-picker/source/checkout is out of date I guess.